# Text-to-Speech Voices on MacOS

Tags: macos, text-to-speech, voice

Is there any documentation about the format Apple uses to save their Text-to-Speech voices?
Is there any application that already can generate such voices?
I'm guessing that most of the information is contained in the file "PCMwave", but I can't figure out what the structure might be.

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the question to "how to create new TTS voices for the Mac" ?